# Problems downloading from Android Market - related to package size?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I regularly get support emails from users who can't download my app from the Android Market. They say that **after purchasing the app, it fails to download.**

The only thing I can think of is apk size: mine is 30MB. My standard reply is to try again on Wi-Fi, but I don't think this has fixed the problem for a significant number of my users.

Specifically:

- **Is there anything other than apk size that could cause this?**
- **Other than slimming down, which I'm planning to do eventually, what might help?**

Comment: does it occur on certain devices only? or is it affecting a good cross section of devices?

Comment: Does your manifest call out a preferred install location (internal vs. sdcard)?  I wonder if there is something with the user having enough space for the app to install but not enough for it to download and install.

Comment: @Nick, no I don't set a preferred location

Comment: @willytate, I haven't seen multiple reports from the same device. It does seem to be around 10% of my users experiencing this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this issue before and usually if I select Market in my Applications list and clear the cache it will fix the issue.

30 MB is a huge download (i think that's the apk limit) so i would definitely implement some type of in app download to sd card like most games do.